# MySQL INSERT - Do field names require backtick/accent delimination?

Tags: php, mysql

I am somewhat new to MySQL (come from MS SQL) and have recently come across something very confusing to me when trying to INSERT values into the database.

I created an INSERT SQL command via PHP yet found it threw an error when trying to execute.

```
INSERT INTO myTableName (first-name, last-name) VALUES ('Ted', 'Johnson')
```

To my way of thinking the above string should have worked .. but it didn't. I even tried using it directly in phpMyAdmin but I got the same syntax error.

The only thing that ended up making it work is if I surrounded the field names in the SQL statement by the "backtick" or "accent" character (the other character on the tilde key on the keyboard). For example ...

```
INSERT INTO myTableName(`first-name`, `last-name`) VALUES ('Ted', 'Johnson')
```

I have never known this to be necessary in MySQL or MS SQL Server. I have always just listed the field names without delimiting them. Has anyone run across this before? I am using MySQL 5.0.77. Thank you.

Comment: If you insist on having silly table names (like names containing a minus, or names that are also SQL keywords), then you need to quote the names. Otherwise you don't.

Comment: did you wrap it in (" ...... ")?

Comment: firstName or first_name or FirstName or firstname are better options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your column names contain hyphens, which is generally not a good idea, since the parser could misinterpret as `first minus name`. The back-ticks are the MySQL method of quoting column names to ensure they're treated correctly.

If your columns were first_name and last_name, the back-ticks would not be necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You only need the backticks if your column names collide with SQL reserved words or symbols. In your case, the dash that separates `first` and `name` (and the one between `last` and `name`) is interpreted as a minus sign. Additionally the word `first` is used in [MySQL's `ALTER TABLE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) (Although it actually doesn't appear in [MySQL's reserved words list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)). If you can rename your columns using underscores instead of dashes to separate words, you won't need the backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, even the SO syntax highlighter is showing `last` as blue in your first code-statement (a little joke.) I'm not a MYSQL pro, but I do always use the backticks, because I want to program myself to always use them. If you use the backticks naturally, you can avoid alot of problems in the future. I would also backtick your table:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `myTableName` (`first-name`, `last-name`) VALUES ('Ted', 'Johnson')");
```

Comment: I'd say that getting yourself used to not using reserved words is an equally good habit. The backticks are MySQL-specific; learning good naming conventions is a far more portable skill...