# All data go to database except name

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i having trouble ajax script. to send data to the database. all go into database except $name, $n.   here my link of code. I can't show it here because it too long. please help me. it almost due date for my submission of final year project at university. please help me, guys. thank you

edited.
 I'm already done it search the problem part by part. in script, it still show the output that I key in the form. but when it comes to the PHP part, the name doesn't send the output to the database.

```
function signup(){

    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var n = _("name").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
...
    ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&n="+n+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
```

---

```
$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$n = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['n']);
$p = $_POST['p'];
$g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
$c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `email`, `name`, `password`, `gender`, `country`, `ip`, `signup`, `lastlogin`, `notescheck`)       
            VALUES(`$u`,`$e`,`$n`,`$p_hash`,`$g`,`$c`,`$ip`,now(),now(),now())"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: So the only quoted string in the insert is name. So perhaps that is it?

Comment: correct. Use backticks instead.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395062/mysql-insert-do-field-names-require-backtick-accent-delimination

Comment: So next time  post relevant code and you would have gotten a lot faster answers. I am not even a PHP programmer but found the problem and a dupe in 5 minutes after looking at actual code

Comment: *"t almost due date for my submission of final year project at university"* highschools or and universities should give minus points when programming code is unsafe ... As `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and or `preg_replace()` is simply not safe enough to protect against all SQL injection vectors ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer already. the problem started when I copy the signup.php to test.php because I want to add name. when i already did the code and run using test.php, it still not showing the code. when i overnight to search in google for an answer, there is an answer to my problem. when i using test.php, it automatically redirects to code that I'm using in signup.php. since the main code doesn't change at all, so name doesn't send to the database. So what I am doing is I delete the test.php and edit directly from signup.php. miracle the name sent to the database when i run the signup.php.. dunno why.

btw, thank guys for helping me and suggest me what to do and don't do. i appreciate all the comments expecially the admin of this website.

thankyou.